# How can I render search on Livewire with an orWhere clause not related to search?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, decimal, render, laravel-livewire

I have here a Livewire render function that displays records depending on what is searched on the textbox. It was working fine, and giving me results in an autocomplete manner. However, when I added this line `->orWhere('qty_on_hand', '!=', 0)`, it stops that autocomplete searching.

```
 <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    
    use Livewire\Component;
    use App\Models\Product;
    
    class LoadInStockProducts extends Component
    {
        public $searchTerm;
        public $amount = 10;
    
        protected $listeners = [
            'load-more' => 'loadMore'
        ];
       
        public function loadMore()
        {
            $this->amount = $this->amount + 10;
        }
    
        public function render()
        {
            $searchTerm = '%' . $this->searchTerm . '%';
            
            $products = Product::orderBy('name')->where('code', 'like', $searchTerm)
                        ->orWhere('name', 'like', $searchTerm)
                        ->orWhere('description', 'like', $searchTerm)
                        ->orWhere('qty_on_hand', '!=', 0)
                        ->paginate($this->amount);
    
            $this->emit('productStore');
            
            return view('livewire.load-in-stock-products', ['products' => $products]);
        }
    }
```

How can I make the autocomplete searching work, even with the `->orWhere('qty_on_hand', '!=', 0)` condition? Also, another question, I've tried this `->orWhere('srp', '!=', 0.00)` and it's not working. How can I make it work for float types? The `srp` field is a float type by the way.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you checked your Product model? is there "qty_on_hand" element in $fillable array??

Comment: Yes. protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'code', 
        'barcode',
        'name',
        'description',
        'dealers_price',
        'srp',
        'qty_on_hand',
        'unit',
        'size',
        'cost',
        'category',
        'supplier',
        'delivery_date',
    ];

Comment: with the grather than operator ">" don't retrieve data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to produce a query where you search for the given fields, and only show the records that has a quantity on hand - that would look like this in raw SQL,

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE (
      code LIKE '%searchterm%'
      OR name LIKE '%searchterm%'
      OR description LIKE '%searchterm%'
   )
   AND qty_on_hand != 0
ORDER BY name
```

Note how the search for code/name/description is within its own group, and that you look for any match of either of those **and** where the quantity is different from zero.

In Laravel, that means you have to group the query as well, using a closure.

```php
$products = Product::where(function($query) use ($searchTerm) {
        return $query->where('code', 'like', $searchTerm)
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', $searchTerm)
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', $searchTerm);
    })
    ->where('qty_on_hand', '!=', 0)
    ->orderBy('name')
    ->paginate($this->amount);
```

You can introduce more groups if you have other conditions, like having two `where()` with a closure, where the queries inside use `orwhere()`.

```php
$products = Product::where(function($query) use ($searchTerm) {
        return $query->where('code', 'like', $searchTerm)
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', $searchTerm)
            ->orWhere('description', 'like', $searchTerm);
    })
    ->where(function($query) {
        return $query->where('qty_on_hand', '!=', 0)
            ->orWhere('srp', '!=', 0);
    })
    ->orderBy('name')
    ->paginate($this->amount);
```

Comment: Yes, correct. This is now working. Thanks so much for your help @Qirel. Another question, how can I add an orWhere() after ->where('qty_on_hand', '!=', 0) for a float type? I was trying this one but doesn't work.  ->where('srp', '!=', 0.00)

Comment: Question is, what is the condition? Where the `search term AND the qty_on_hand != 0 AND srp != 0`? Or, is it `search term AND (qty_on_and != 0 OR srp != 0)`? If you don't know how to describe it with SQL, describe it with words :)

Comment: Noted. Uhm this one: `search term AND (qty_on_and != 0 OR srp != 0)` . By the way in `srp != 0.00`, 0.00 is in float type.

Comment: See my revised answer -- as you can see, the approach is the same as the searchterm-block.

Comment: Thank you @Qirel. It still however didn't work. I've moved this to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69039113/how-can-i-get-data-in-laravel-eloquent-where-a-field-is-not-equal-to-a-zero-deci