# How can I get data in Laravel Eloquent where a field is not equal to a zero decimal value?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, decimal, where-clause, floor

I have here a query that retrieves products with search and another query where fields are not equal to zero. However, I have one field (srp) where it should return data if values is not equal to a zero decimal value. The srp field is a price value by the way, that is why it's decimal. Here's my query.

```
 public function render()
{
    $searchTerm = '%' . $this->searchTerm . '%';
    
    $products = Product::where(function($query) use ($searchTerm) {
    return $query->where('code', 'like', $searchTerm)
        ->orWhere('name', 'like', $searchTerm)
        ->orWhere('description', 'like', $searchTerm);
    }) ->where(function($query) {
        return $query->where('qty_on_hand', '!=', 0)
             ->orWhereRaw('srp != FLOOR(0.00)');
    })
    ->orderBy('name')
    ->paginate($this->amount);

    $this->emit('productStore');
    
    return view('livewire.load-in-stock-products', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

Here's the line of code I'm trying to fix: `->orWhereRaw('srp != FLOOR(0.00)');`

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete code. It's on wildcard. Please see updated question above.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the `->orWhereRaw('srp != FLOOR(0.00)');` is already working. Sorry as I didn't know. It was because I was looking at another field, **cost**. Again, the query on the question above is already the correct answer.